On connectedness of integers under arithmatic topology
I want to show $\mathbb{Z}$ is totally disconnected under arithmatic topology with basis $A(a, b)$ := {$a \mathbb Z + b$} = {$an + b : n ∈ \mathbb Z$},
where $a, b ∈ \mathbb Z$ and $a \not= 0$.
each basis element is clopen and for $a>0, a\in\mathbb Z$ we have $$\mathbb{Z}=\bigcup_{n=0}^{a-1} A(a,n)$$
which shows basis are clopen but it leades nowhere to show that it is totally disconnected.
this space is clearly housedorff.
